# pmd:DataflowAnomalyAnalysis generates false positives for enhanced for loops?

Tags: java, sonarqube, pmd

[image: screenshot]

SonarQube seems to be complaining about row 64. This can't be right or have I misunderstood the rule?

**My setup:** SonarQube 4.5.4 LTS, PMD plugin 2.3

Comment: This question should be asked directly to the PMD development team.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the PMD issue tracker (after the pointer from Freddy) I could find that this is a known issue: https://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/bugs/1190/